# runnable .jar file runs on my windows device but won't on others(windows too)

Tags: java, jar, export, runnable

So I've made up a little programm for my mom to use. I exported it into a `runnable .jar`, which is a first for me, so I obviously screwed it up.

Actually the file works just fine on my computer. But when I try it on hers, double clicking on the file just gives me an error : "could not find Main class : controller.Main". And the programm won't start

I used eclipse GUI to export it (right click on projet -> export -> runnable JAR), and it gave out a file working well on my computer.
If it is of any help, my programm uses a bunch of resources files, but I included them in the right place in the folder that I gave to my mother so it should not be the problem (besides, it would glitch out when trying to use the images, but not stop it from launching, according to some personnal tests)

What can be the Reason for it to work on my device, but not another one (both Windows) ? And how to fix this ?

N.B: I have included a MANIFEST.MS file in my project before exporting, but Eclipse didn't make any explicit mention to it when exporting, so I think it didn't take it into account. Besides, I reffered to my main class as `Main` (and not `controller.Main` as in the error message I got on my mother's computer). This was probably wrong of me, but I think it shows that Eclipse didn't care much for my manifest and kinda made his own.

Thanks in advance !
If you want a link to download the folder, to check it out yourself, let me know ! (it's a bit heavy though, there's quite a lot of images)

EDIT : I get different error messages with different computer. One computer would give me this first message : 
[first computer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccv4S.png)

Another computer gives me those 2 error messages (one after another)

[2nd computer error (1/2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6e0x.png)

[2nd computer error 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uegup.png)

And of course, it still runs fine on mine, just with a double click !

My .jar file (opened as an archive) contains :

- 3 folders corresponding to my packages : controller, model, view
- 1 folder META-INF containing the MANIFEST.MF generated by eclipse, looking like so :

  `Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Main-Class: controller.Main
  Class-Path: .`

Comment: When you create a runnable jar file with eclipse, the MANIFEST will be generated automatically by eclipse. If you want to include your own MANIFEST with "Main-class: Main" then you should do projet -> export -> JAR on eclipse and select your MANIFEST file. Have you tried opening both jar files (the one on your computer and the one on your mother's) using RAR or ZIP (perhaps the contents are different) ?

Comment: Thanks for this precison on the manifest, but I trust Eclipse's more than mine actually :D I didn't try to open the jar, because they really are the same files (i just copied the one from my computer on a USB key, and gave it). Do you think thare could be any difference ?

Comment: Could you write / print the full stack trace / error ?

Comment: Of course. Check the edited message for a screenshot of the various errors I get on different computers

Comment: You mention some resource files. Are these resources DLL files? Are you using native function calls (operating system dependant)?

Comment: By resource files, I merely meant some images, gifs and sound effects used by the program, that are in a "resources" folder next to the the runnable.JAR. Sorry if it was an inappropriate term for this. After a quick search on what a native function actually is (I'm that bad ^^), I Don't think I am using any. Although, to be honest, I am still not 100% sure of what it is :S

Comment: ok then. What version of java is installed in both computers (you can find that out by running `java -version` in the terminal) Can you show your jar's structure and the MANIFEST file in it? (you can open it with rar or zip)

Comment: Ok, so the first computer (first error report in my message) tells me  that he can't recognize "java" as an internal or external command, and so on. But I could find a java folder (in theProgram Files) containing a JRE6 folder... The second gives me a 1.8.0_171 version. For the .jar file, check the editied message

Comment: Ok configure the java environment variables on the first computer check this out: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html . Make sure the PATH env variable references JAVA_HOME so that you can run java from the terminal. It seems that java is not correctly installed on the second computer, try installing the latest one. Once everything is configured, try running the jar from the terminal like this 'java -cp ./myjar.jar controller.Main'  (assuming the jar name is myjar.jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! I could figure it out. So there were actually 2 problems on top of each other :

- first, I think Martin's suggestion was correct. After researches on the new error message, it became clear that native calls had probably had Something to do with the problem, although I have no idea what native Library I was using. I could solve this first part of the problem by selecting another option to handle libraries in the eclipse export feature : I chose the option "package required libraries into genereated JAR" (instead of "extract required libraries into generated JAR" before), and it make the error message go away !
- Even though the message disappeared, the app would still not launch. But the problem was more obvious this time; I Simply compiled and exported the file with a java 9 JDK for eclipse, while trying to run it on a java 8 software (I think java 9 is only available in its developper version to this day). So I just downloaded java 8 JDK, configured the build path to use the latter, and it finally worked on the other computer.

Thanks to Martin who helped me get on track with the right questions !